# Loop Through a list in python to query DynamoDB for each item

Tags: python-3.x, dynamodb-queries

I have a list of items and would like to use each item as the pk (Primary Key) to query Dynamo DB, using Python.

I have tried using a for loop but I dont get any results, If I try the same query with the actual value from the group_id list it does work which means my query statement is correct.

```
group_name_query = []

for i in group_id:
    group_name_query = config_table.query(
        KeyConditionExpression=Key('pk').eq(i) & Key('sk').eq('GROUP')
        )
```

Here is a sample group_ip = ['GROUP#6501e5ac-59b2-4d05-810a-ee63d2f4f826', 'GROUP#6501e5ac-59b2-4d05-810a-ee63d2sfdgd']

Answer (score 0):

not answering your issue but got a suggestion, if you're querying base table with pk and sk instead of query gsi, i would suggest you  `Batch Get Item` API to get multiple items in one shot

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/example_dynamodb_BatchGetItem_section.html